# PostgreSQL retrieving duplicate row records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running a PostgreSQL query, but it retrieves duplicate row records, which I don't need? #PleaseHelp

Would appreciate; if someone suggest, or improve my original query, thank you.

I used distinct, groupby and having clauses, but still it retrieves duplicate row records.

```
SET statement_timeout TO 9000000;

SELECT 
      sp.sku
     ,soi.product_id
     ,sc.name
     ,sp.name
     ,sp.active
     ,sp.stock AS total_stock
     ,sp.actual_stock
     ,sp.virtual_stock
     ,sp.price AS current_proce
     ,date(sp.created::timestamp AT time zone 'utc' AT time zone 'asia/kolkata')
     ,CURRENT_DATE - date(sp.created::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AT TIME ZONE 'asia/kolkata') AS days_since_created
     ,DATE_PART('week', date(sp.created::timestamp AT time zone 'utc' AT time zone 'asia/kolkata')) AS week
      ,sum(soi.quanity) AS units_sold
     ,((soi.price* sum(soi.quanity)) - sum(soi.discount)) AS Revenue_Before_Tax
     ,case
          WHEN sc.name = 'Accessories' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price * sum(soi.quanity) * 70) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100)
          WHEN sc.name = 'Apparel' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity) * 70) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price* sum(soi.quanity)* 70) - SUM(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Wellness' AND so.currency ='USD' THEN ((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity))*70 - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity) * 70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Footwear' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price* sum(soi.quanity)*70) - SUM(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Bags' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity)*70) - SUM(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price* sum(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Jewelry'AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity*70)) - sum(soi.discount))- round((((soi.price* sum(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Home & Decor' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price* sum(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Mother & Child' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price* sum(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          ELSE ((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity)) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price*sum(soi.quanity)) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
             END AS revenue_after_tax
        ,round(ng.revenue_after_tax / ng.units_sold) AS average_selling_price
FROM
   order_order AS so
LEFT JOIN 
   order_orderproduct AS soi ON so.id = soi.order_id  
LEFT JOIN
   store_product AS sp ON soi.product_id = sp.id
LEFT JOIN
    store_category AS sc ON sp.category_id = sc.id
LEFT JOIN
    tms_hsncode AS hsn ON sp.hsncode_id = hsn.id
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT
      sp.sku AS gt
     ,sp.id
     ,sc.name
     ,sp.name
     ,sp.active
     ,sp.stock AS total_stock
     ,sp.actual_stock
     ,sp.virtual_stock
     ,sp.price AS current_proce
     ,date(sp.created::timestamp AT time zone 'utc' AT time zone 'asia/kolkata')
     ,CURRENT_DATE - date(sp.created::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AT TIME ZONE 'asia/kolkata') AS days_since_created
     ,DATE_PART('week', date(sp.created::timestamp AT time zone 'utc' AT time zone 'asia/kolkata')) AS week
      ,count(soi.quanity) AS units_sold
     ,((soi.price* count(soi.quanity)) - sum(soi.discount)) AS Revenue_Before_Tax
     ,case
          WHEN sc.name = 'Accessories' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price * count(soi.quanity) * 70) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price*count(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100)
          WHEN sc.name = 'Apparel' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*count(soi.quanity) * 70) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price* count(soi.quanity)* 70) - SUM(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Wellness' AND so.currency ='USD' THEN ((soi.price*count(soi.quanity))*70 - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price*count(soi.quanity) * 70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Footwear' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*count(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price* count(soi.quanity)*70) - SUM(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Bags' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*count(soi.quanity)*70) - SUM(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price* count(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Jewelry'AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*count(soi.quanity*70)) - sum(soi.discount))- round((((soi.price*count(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Home & Decor' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*count(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price*count(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          WHEN sc.name = 'Mother & Child' AND so.currency = 'USD' THEN ((soi.price*count(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price*count(soi.quanity)*70) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
          ELSE ((soi.price*count(soi.quanity)) - sum(soi.discount)) - round((((soi.price*count(soi.quanity)) - sum(soi.discount))*hsn.tax::integer)/100) 
             END AS revenue_after_tax
FROM
   order_order AS so
LEFT JOIN 
   order_orderproduct AS soi ON so.id = soi.order_id  
LEFT JOIN
   store_product AS sp ON soi.product_id = sp.id
LEFT JOIN
    store_category AS sc ON sp.category_id = sc.id
LEFT JOIN
    tms_hsncode AS hsn ON sp.hsncode_id = hsn.id
WHERE
    sp.created::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AT TIME ZONE 'asia/kolkata' >= CURRENT_DATE - 100
GROUP BY
      sp.sku
     ,sp.id
     ,soi.price
     ,so.currency
     ,hsn.tax
     ,sc.name
     ,sp.name
     ,sp.active
     ,sp.stock 
     ,sp.actual_stock
     ,sp.virtual_stock
     ,sp.price 
     ,sp.created
     ,days_since_created
     ,week ) AS ng ON sp.sku = ng.gt
WHERE
    sp.created::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AT TIME ZONE 'asia/kolkata' >= CURRENT_DATE - 100
GROUP BY
      sp.sku
     ,soi.product_id
     ,soi.price
     ,so.currency
     ,hsn.tax
     ,sc.name
     ,sp.name
     ,sp.active
     ,sp.stock 
     ,sp.actual_stock
     ,sp.virtual_stock
     ,sp.price 
     ,sp.created
     ,days_since_created
     ,week
     ,ng.revenue_after_tax
     ,ng.units_sold
;
```

I need output in following format

sku, product_id, .....................average selling price

Comment: What do you consider a "Duplicate Row" in this case? According to your last `GROUP BY` there should be no repeats among the list of columns `sp.sku
     ,soi.product_id
     ,soi.price
     ,so.currency
     ,hsn.tax
     ,sc.name
     ,sp.name
     ,sp.active
     ,sp.stock 
     ,sp.actual_stock
     ,sp.virtual_stock
     ,sp.price 
     ,sp.created
     ,days_since_created
     ,week
,ng.revenue_after_tax
,ng.units_sold` it's safe to say you aren't getting two identical rows there. Beyond that without seeing your data and desired results... there isn't much we can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on any query:

select distinct * 
from ($query$) $table_alias_for_query;

A better way should be adding distinct in the original query (I didn't notice distinct in your query).